# Rails: optimizing a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, if-statement, logic

I have the following method that checks user birthdate (in "%d/%m/%Y" format) to be at least 18.

```
  def person_age
    if person_birthdate.present?
      now = Time.now.utc.to_date
      begin
        parsedDate = Date.parse(person_birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y')

        diff = now.year - parsedDate.year
        diff -= (diff.years.since(parsedDate) > now ? 1 : 0)

        if diff < 18
          errors.add :person_birthdate, 'You should be at least 18'
        end
      rescue
        errors.add :person_birthdate, 'Date not valid'
      end
    else
      errors.add :person_birthdate, 'Date not valid'
    end
  end
```

But too many if conditions, any idea how to make it look better?

Comment: It seems like you store the birthday as a string in your database. Why do you do that? If it was a date column Rails would handle the parsing for you and your validation would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use built-in and custom validations.

```
validates :person_birthdate, presence: true
validate  :check_age, if: -> { person_birthdate.present? }

private

def check_age
  date = Date.parse(person_birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y')
  unless d > 18.years.ago
    errors.add(:person_birthdate, 'message here')
  end
end
```

`if: -> { person_birthdate.present? }` allows to call custom validation only when the condition is `true`.

Comment: `allow_nil: true` doesn't prevent you from getting to errors, the if does.  `allow_nil: true` isn't needed .

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just add `if` after it. I will update answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
validates_presence_of :person_birthdate # which will generate the "Date is required message"
```

and something like:

```
def person_age
  date = Date.parse(person_birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y')
  unless d > 18.years.ago
    errors.add :person_birthdate, "You should be at least 18."    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is good in some aspects, but here all these `validate[s]` are an overkill:

```
def person_age
  case Date.today - Date.parse(
         person_birthdate, '%d/%m/%Y'
       ).advance(years: 18) rescue nil
  when NilClass
    errors.add :person_birthdate, 'Date not valid'
  when -Float::INFINITY..0
    errors.add :person_birthdate, 'You should be at least 18'
  else puts "Allowed!"
  end
end
```